# How to draw one row from a MySQL query when the unique id doesn't match 7 others queried

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a news story database and I have a most read section.  My news is displayed in a block of 8 stories.  The first 7 are drawn from the following MySQL query below and displays the top 7 most read stories of the last 7 days(DESC). This works as I would expect and displays the top 7 most read news stories.

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
    FROM news 
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(day, '%d %M %Y') >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
 ORDER 
      BY mostRead DESC 
 LIMIT 7
";

$results = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)or die('Error querying database');

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){

echo news stories

}
```

I'm struggling on how to form the next MySQL query.  The 8th news story I need to display needs to be the first story in my database that is not also in the top 7 most read news stories. This is to avoid duplication in the block of 8 stories.

For example if a new news stories has a rush of hits, I don't want it to appear in the top 7 and then also as the 8th news story because it is also still the newest entry.

Comment: Note that functions cannot use indexes, so performance will be immeasurably improved if you can think of a way to remove them

Comment: @StevenLafferty . . . I'm confused.  Why not just change the "7" to and "8" to get the 8 top news stories?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` or `rank()` for this:

```
order by
    case when rank() over(order by mostRead desc) <= 7,
        then mostRead 
        else 0
    end desc,
    str_to_date(day, '%d %M %Y') desc
limit 8
```

The conditional expression in first sort criteria returns `mostRead` if it the current row is ranked amongst the top 7, else it yields `0` (so all other rows are tied). Then, the second sort criteria uses the date. All that is left to do is limit the resultset to 8 rows.

Comment: My MySQL is very limited and I use phpMyAdmin, provided by my service provider and from what I can gather under database server it is on version: Server version: 5.7.23-23 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 23, Revision 500fcf5. Not even close to MySQL 8.0!  Dose this mean that the above suggested function will not run?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to add an extra row to your result set. These queries will work for older MySQL versions (tested on 5.7.26).

There are few options how to achieve that, you can add top 8 rows from your table and let `UNION` filter the duplicates and then pick only one record by adding `LIMIT 8` to the end of the query:

```sql
(SELECT *
   FROM news
   WHERE STR_TO_DATE(day, '%d %M %Y') >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
   ORDER BY mostRead DESC
   LIMIT 7)
UNION
  (SELECT *
   FROM news
   ORDER BY str_to_date(day, '%d %M %Y') DESC
   LIMIT 8)
LIMIT 8
```

Or you can filter the rows yourself which is more suitable for advanced use cases.

```sql
  (SELECT *
   FROM news
   WHERE STR_TO_DATE(DAY, '%d %M %Y') >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
   ORDER BY mostRead DESC
   LIMIT 7)
UNION
  (SELECT *
   FROM news
   WHERE id NOT IN
       (SELECT id
        FROM
          (SELECT *
           FROM news
           WHERE STR_TO_DATE(day, '%d %M %Y') >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
           ORDER BY mostRead DESC
           LIMIT 7) temp)
   ORDER BY str_to_date(day, '%d %M %Y') DESC
   LIMIT 1)
```

We've added `temp` table because old versions of MySQL do not support LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. As I said I'm not an expert, but I will work through these and let you now how I get on.  Very much appreciate the comments, thank you

Answer (score 0):

> The 8th news story I need to display needs to be the first story in my database that is not also in the top 7 most read news stories.

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM news n
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(day, '%d %M %Y') >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
ORDER BY mostRead DESC 
LIMIT 8
------^ this is the change
```

If you already have the 7 in your application and need to get a different one then you need to deal with the ids:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM news n
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(day, '%d %M %Y') >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND
     n.id NOT IN ($id1, $id2, $id3, $id4, $id5, $id6, $id7)
ORDER BY mostRead DESC 
LIMIT 1
```